# Is dynamic memory allocation in C++11 thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is allocation and deallocation of dynamic memory in C++11 thread-safe? In other words: Can threads use `new` and `delete` as freely as single-threaded code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, dynamic allocation by `::operator new` and deallocation by `::operator delete` is thread-safe. An implementation is however permitted to have a global lock (e.g. on `malloc` called by `new`) which would serialize the allocation. If your program redefines `::operator new`  & `::operator delete` it should ensure that they are thread-safe.

Regarding `delete` you should not delete the same pointer twice (e.g. in two different threads).

Comment: Thank you! Regarding `delete`, you should never delete the same pointer twice - not in two different threads, not in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks, improved my answer.